# probability of picking a winner

Tags: probability

Three runners compete in a race. The probability that A will win the race is twice the probability that B will win. The probability that B will win is twice the probability that C will win. What is the exact probability that A will win the race?

This is like one of those questions you used to get as a kid. I'm not sure where to begin since probability is still new to me. Any suggestions or tips?

Answer (score 4):

You have that $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$ since one of them has to win and also $P(A)=2\cdot P(B)$ and $P(B)=2 \cdot P(C)$ and thus $P(A)=4 \cdot P(C)$.

Substituting in the first equation we get $4 \cdot P(C)+2 \cdot P(C)+ P(C)=1$, thus $P(C)=1/7$. It follows then $P(B)=2/7$ and $P(A)=4/7$.